# Java How to Filter List of JPA Objects That Contain Several Nested Levels of Lists

Tags: java, list, jpa, filter

I am trying to filter a list of JPA objects that contain several levels of nested lists.  I need to filter the top level list based on criterial in the list that is 2 levels down.

My application is given a list of Orders that contains a list of OrderLines that contains a list of OrderLineDetails.  I am trying to filter the orderLineDetail list that is contained within the list of Orders to the most recent statusTs for each OrderLine within the list. The final result should be a list of Orders that contains the most recent OrderLineDetail for each OrderLine.  I am running into issues because the orderLineDetail list is a child object 2 levels down from the Order object.  Can someone provide an example of how this can be done?  Thanks for your help.

```
public class Order

private Long orderId;

@OneToMany(
    mappedBy = "order",
    cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
    fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private List<OrderLine> orderLines = new ArrayList<>();
...
```

```
public class OrderLine

private Long orderLineId;
private Timestamp lastUpdate;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "orderLine", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private List<OrderLineDetail> orderLineDetails;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "orderId")
private Order order;
...
```

```
public class OrderLineDetail

private Long orderLineDetailId;
private Integer status;
private Instant statusTs = Instant.now();

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "orderLineId")
private OrderLine orderLine;
...
```

Not sure if there is a better way.  But this seems to work.

```
  public List<Order> filterOrdersByMostRecentTs(List<Order> orderList) {

    orderList.forEach(order -> {
      order.getOrderLine().forEach(line -> {
        List<OrderLineDetail> orderLineDetailList = line.getOrderLineDetail();
        Map<Object, Object> o =
            orderLineDetailList.stream().collect(
                Collectors.groupingBy(OrderLineDetail -> OrderLineDetail.getOrderLine().getOrderLineId(),
                    Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                        Collectors.reducing((OrderLineDetail d1, OrderLineDetail d2) -> d1.getStatusTs().getEpochSecond() > d2.getStatusTs().getEpochSecond()? d1 : d2),
                        Optional::get)));
        orderLineDetailList.clear();
        o.forEach((k, v) -> orderLineDetailList.add((OrderLineDetail) v));
      });
    });

    return orderList;
  }
```

Comment: What do you mean by word filter? Filter can mean get rid of heavy objects and don't load heavy graph of objects. Filter can also mean to make special select and use criteria on the nested objects which are 2 level inside.

Comment: I want to remove all of the items from the orderLineDetails list except the item with the most recent statusTs for each OrderLine within the list.  The final result should be a list of Orders that contains the most recent OrderLineDetail for each OrderLine.

Comment: I think this is not JPA question. You can edit the objects with pure java after you load them from DB. Just make sure to evict them so the changes not be persisted in your DB. If this is what you want, I will try to make a working example for you.